# Combining multiple matrices into one data frame

Tags: r

I'm using the following code to scrape info on houses (e.g. address and sales period):

```
scrape_func <- function(url) {
  library(rvest)
  library(stringr)
  Sys.sleep(0.25)
  
  webpage <- read_html(url)
  boligsiden <- webpage %>%
    html_nodes("script") %>%
    html_text()
  
  webpage <- read_html(url)
  bolig_adresse <- webpage %>%
    html_nodes("div.t-truncate.t-bold") %>%
    html_text()
  
  liggetid_final <- as.matrix(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(boligsiden, '(?<="salesPeriod":")[^"]+'))))
  
  udbudt_final <- as.matrix(unlist(str_extract_all(boligsiden, '(?<="dateAdded":")[^"]+')), tryFormats=c("%d-%m-%Y"))
  
  solgt_final <- as.matrix(unlist(str_extract_all(boligsiden, '(?<="dateRemoved":")[^"]+')), tryFormats=c("%d-%m-%Y"))
  
  scrape <- unique(cbind(bolig_adresse[1], liggetid_final, udbudt_final, solgt_final))
  
  return(scrape)
  
}

links <- sapply(df_all$link, as.character)

scrape <- data.frame(rbind(sapply(links, scrape_func)))
```

When I run the last line(`scrape <- data.frame(rbind(sapply(links, scrape_func)))`), I get the following warning message:

```
In cbind(bolig_adresse[1], liggetid_final, udbudt_final, solgt_final) :
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1),
```

and the data frame just consists of 1 obs and 60 variables. There are 60 different webpages, but multiple lines for each webpage (since there are multiple sales for most of the houses), so the end data frame should contain more than 60 rows and exactly 4 columns.

When I just use `scrape <- unique(cbind(adresse[1], liggetid_final, udbudt_final, solgt_final))` on one website (for one house), it works just fine.

Scaling it up, I just want r to stack the matrices on top of each other into one big data frame, but I just can't figure out how to do that.

Additional info:

An example of a url:
https://www.boligsiden.dk/adresse/ledoejevej-21-2620-albertslund-01650298__21_______
For this particular municipality there is around 3000 different houses and I need to combine the data from each of them into one data set.

One url might return:
[address1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbinc.png)

And another may return:
[address2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ryYy.png)

However, it seems that the `do.call` does the trick, but I still get the warning messages.

Comment: Perhaps, you need `do.call(rbind, lapply(links, scrape_func))`

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible example? If not, a toy dataset that mimics your problem?

Comment: Please provide url if possible

Comment: A minimal reproducible example really helps us help you. See the official Stack Overflow vignette on how to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I added a bit to the original question.

Comment: I see 404 for that url. Is it definitely correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your URLs is returning zero rows, raising the warning. Your code is probably also flattening out the result.

```
scrape_func <- function(m) {
    unique(cbind(m[1], m))
}
links <- list(as.matrix(head(women, n = 2)), as.matrix(head(women, n = 0)))
scrape <- data.frame(rbind(sapply(links, scrape_func)))
# Warning message:
#     In cbind(m[1], m) :
#     number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
scrape
#                         X1 X2
# 1 58, 58, 58, 59, 115, 117
```

Instead you want to enforce the structure of the output of `scrape_func` despite the result.

```
scrape_func <- function(m) {
    scrape <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = max(length(m[1]), length(m)), 
        dimnames = list(NULL, c("bolig_adresse", "liggetid_final")))
    scrape[seq_along(m[1]), 1] <- m[1]
    scrape[seq_along(c(m)), 2] <- c(m)
    as.data.frame(unique(scrape))
}
links <- list(as.matrix(head(women, n = 2)), as.matrix(head(women, n = 0)))
scrape <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(links, scrape_func))
scrape
#   bolig_adresse liggetid_final
# 1            58             58
# 2            NA             59
# 3            NA            115
# 4            NA            117
# 5            NA             NA
```

Also, prefer to avoid using `sapply`, having your code decide when to simplify the output almost always leads to bugs at some point. :)

Comment: How did you get the provided url to work?

Comment: @QHarr, I did not, this is toy data simulating the problem. :)

Comment: Aha :-) Thought I was going crazier.  Nice. Thanks. I didn't look properly and see the matrix creation.